# How to check if data is returned from api?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, vue.js

How to check if my api request returns me any data from `fetchData` function?, I want to return `boolean`(or something else) to my `Index.vue` and show loader when data is loading but when data is loaded then i want to use: `this.$router.push("admin/dashboard")` to redirect to another page where this data is displayed,

my code:

```
const actions = {
    fetchData({ commit },{ id}) {
        return axios.get(`someUrl?hd=${id}`)
            .then(response => {
                if(response.status == 200) {
                    commit('setData', response.data),
                }
            })
            .catch(
                error => {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
        
    }
}
```

`Index.vue`

```
 <div v-if="isDataLoaded" class="loading-div">
    <vue-spinner />
 </div>


 methods: {
      ...mapActions(["fetchData"]),
      launchFetchData() {
        new Promise(() => {
          this.$store.dispatch("fetchData", {
            id: this.id
          })
        })
 }
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

you can use:    `console.log(response.data)`

Answer (score 1):

When you set your data to response.data, use the .length to check the size. If it's > 0 then route the user to the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Use Js  Promises in this way.. The next all statements will pause until the promise resolve an issue

```html
<body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<script>

function makeGetRequest(path) { 
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
        axios.get(path).then( 
            (response) => { 
                var result = response.status; 
                console.log('Processing Request'); 
                resolve(result); 
            }, 
                (error) => { 
                reject(error); 
            } 
        ); 
    }); 
} 

async function main() { 
    var result = await makeGetRequest('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1'); 
    console.log("Status ", result); 
    console.log('Statement 1'); 
    console.log('Statement 2'); 
} 
main(); 

console.log('starting....');

</script>
</body>
```

reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-javascript-wait-for-a-api-request-to-return/